# Writing Fixed length records into a file c++

Tags: c++, file, fstream, fixed-length-record

I'm trying to write N fixed length record of type struct

```
const int N = 101;
char dummay[] = "#####";

struct hashTable
{
   char  name[51];
   int RRN;
};
int main(){
    fstream f("hashFile.txt");
    f.seekp(0,ios::beg);
    hashTable h;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ ) {
       strcpy(h.name,dummay);
       h.RRN = i;
       f.write((char*)&h,sizeof h);
     }
```

and when I'm trying to output these records again, only the first 25 records works well!

```
f.seekp(0,ios::beg);
for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++ )
{
    f.read((char*)&h,sizeof h);
    cout << h.RRN << endl << h.name << endl;
}
```

the complete [code](http://ideone.com/Ln6PRp), why this happens and how to solve it ?!

Comment: Use proper variable names

Comment: The code you show on ideone is outputting more than 25 records correctly.

Comment: just 25 records are correctly on my computer, however the problem solved, see the first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are obviously writing binary data into your file (the int, the null terminator in name and the 45 garbage chars that might follow the name).

So open it in binary mode and it'll work well:

```
fstream f("hashFile.txt", ios::binary);
```

When reading the file in text mode, depending on your os, some binary chars might be interpreted as end of file marker.  For example [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z) (which happen by chance to be ascii code **26**)